# How to fix 'ArgumentCountError' while using page object model in behat

Tags: automation, drupal-8, behat

I am trying to use page object model in my behat framework . Here is my code snippet.

***HomePage.php***

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page;

class HomePage extends Page implements Context{
    protected $path = '/';

}
```

***FeatureContext.php***

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page;

class FeatureContext extends Page implements Context, \Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    private $homepage;

    public function __construct(HomePage $homepage)
    {
        $this->homepage = $homepage;
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^(?:|I )visited (?:|the )(?P<pageName>.*?)$/
     */
    public function iVisitedThe($pageName)
    {
        if (!isset($this->$pageName)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unrecognised page: "%s".', $pageName));
        }
        $this->$pageName->open();
    }
}
```

But while executing the behat tests I am getting the following error ->***"ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page::__construct(), 0 passed and at least 2 expected"***

Answer (score 0):

The setup should be like this:

feature > contexts > page objects

Feature file uses definitions that are defined in the context files and a Context file implements the actual step by calling actions from different page objects.

Your page object should extend just Page.
The Feature context should extend MinkContext and implement Context.
All the other contexts should just implement Context.

Ps: take a look again at the page object extension documentation on Working with page objects topic.